# What does the verb "luere" mean in the Angilberti carmina?

Tags: verbs, rhetoric

Angilbert is asking what the women (the sisters and daughters of Charles the Great) might think of the return of their nephew/brother Pepin from Italy in the poem AD PIPPINUM ITALIAE REGEM by Angilbert :

> (...)
>   Quid Gisla et Theodrada simul cum prole retractant
>      Cetera regali, quas tuus angit amor?
>   Quid Gisla, egregii sponsa praepulchra tonantis,
>      Quid Liutgardis, ovans regis amore luat?

Translation:

> What is it Gisla and Theodrada and the rest of the royal offspring are thinking right now, who are worried about you because of their love?
>   What "luat" Gisla, the beautiful wife of maginificent God, and what "luat" Liutgardis while being jubilant because of her love for the king ?

Does "luere" mean something like "pay tribute"? What might this mean?

Comment: Sorry to be slow in replying. Without the rest of the poem it is difficult to guess the tone, I hope my answer is helpful, but I may be completely off-key. If you discover a better translation, you are encouraged to answer your own question (and earn points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this piece is ***quas tuas angit amor*** ‘whom your love torments.’

Angilbert uses enantiosemy **three times** to convey the uncertainty and (*angit!*)**anx**iety. (Double meaning in the Carolingian Court is almost always a sign of wit and scholarship [jon LLStackExch 1143](http://www.dmgh.de/de/fs1/object/goToPage/bsb00000687.html?pageNo=59&sortIndex=010%3A060%3A0007%3A010%3A00%3A00)) Does *retractant* mean ‘undertake anew?’ or does it mean ‘be reluctant, hesitate?’ he uses a word which has both meanings.

> *re-trāctō (-trectō āvī, ātus, āre)*   be reluctant , hesitate
>   or    ....    to undertake anew. [Lewis&Short Perseus Tufts](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3Dr%3Aentry%20group%3D11%3Aentry%3Dretracto)
>
> *ango, xi, ctum, and anxum,* 3, v. a. to distress, torment, torture
>   or    ....    to embrace, to surround Lewis & Short ([Perseus.uchicago](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:2563.lewisandshort.4389655))
>
> *luo*  make amends, expiate, suffer punishment for
>   or....    loose, let go, be free [(Lewis&Short)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=luo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060)

*Luo* in particular has two meanings, two etymologies, both loan words from Greek, lŭo ere lui from λουω (wash) which gives Latin compounds diluo and eluo.
Lŭo ere lui from λυω (loosen) which gives the Latin compounds solvo (soluo), dissolvo.

So, leaving out three descriptive phrases, and translating *quid* as How!

> Quid Gisla et Theodrada simul retractant?
>   (quas tuus angit amor)
>   Quid Gisla,
>   Quid Liutgardis, luat?
>
> How Gisla and Theodrada at the same time resolve **and** hesitate!
>    (they whom your love strangles **and** enfolds)
>   How Gisla is,
>   how Liutgardis is liberated **and** goes through torment!

Note:**enantiosemy** (OUP) 
A case of polysemy in which one sense is in some respect the opposite of another.

Note: Quid adv. interrog.
'How they guzzle and booze!' *Quid comedent! ebibent!* ([Perseus Tufts L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3Dq%3Aentry%20group%3D3%3Aentry%3Dquid1))

Comment: Thank you very much, Hugh, for your answer. It sheds a new light on this poem for me. I thought that Angilbert was over-cautious in naming the relations between Pepin and his family. But now I see that Angilbert is not exactly cautious, he is sharp! Great!

Answer (score 1):

The verb *luo* is a cognate of the Greek λύω, which means to destroy or loose, often in the sense of undoing a legal obligation or relationship. The Greek word is similar in meaning to the Latin *solvo*. When comparing λύω with the Latin *luo*, a similar sense can be observed. For instance, one of the definitions given by [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=luo&la=la#lexicon) is?

> to render void, of no effect

I think that makes most sense in this context. Given that *quid* can mean "why" and *luat* is in the subjunctive, I understand the meaning to be something like:

> Why should Liutgard, in her happiness, disengage from the love of
>   the king?

And just to clarify, I'm not suggesting that *to disengage* is a precise translation for *luere*, because I believe *luere*, in this case, expresses the idea of dissolving whatever bond of love that might have existed. However, I thought that "disengage" sounded more natural and succinct for expressing that idea.

Comment: Thank you, EB! In fact, I think you are going in the same direction as Hugh, who gave the answer that was complete, You also point to the ambiguity of the phrase. I will read poems like this with ambiguity from now.

Comment: @LiesbethAgelink. You're welcome.